# Каким образом в функции может сохраняться значение переменной?

Tags: javascript, javascript-faq

Изучаю `JS` на http://learn.javascript/, сейчас читаю подраздел «Замыкание функции изнутри» раздела «Замыкания, область видимости».
В пункте [«Возврат функции»](https://learn.javascript.ru/closures#%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8) описывается пример с вложенной функцией.

Я, собственно, не понимаю, как `counter` при каждом запуске вспоминает переменную `currentCount`, учитывая написанное в том же разделе, что `LexicalEnviroment` при каждом завершении функции стирается из памяти, а при каждом новом запуске создается заново.

Не пойму, где хранится `currentCount`, если лексическое окружение стирается каждый раз?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Такие вопросы вызывают у меня скупую слезу на бороду.

Всё просто - `LexicalEnvironment` действительно уничтожается после окончания работы вызова.
Но в примере работа не закончена, т. к. возвращаемая функция сохранила ссылку на родительский [`makeCounter`] объект переменных.

То есть пока возвращенная функция будет жива, родительский LE **обязан** сохранится, вдруг при выполнении нужно обратится к родительской функции за переменными (что и происходит: в возвращённой функции нет переменной `currentCount`)?

Сборщики мусора работают по алгоритму ссылок (Mark and sweep), в общих чертах это как-то так:

- Находятся корни, т. е. то, что всегда будет существовать (в браузерах это объект `window`, его же нельзя удалить).
- После каждого пробуждения, он [сборщик] рекурсивно обходит корни и помечает всё, до чего может дотянутся; это считается как нужное и полезное. Всё остальное считается недостижимым и память из-под них возвращается среде.

А теперь вспомним, что возвращённая функция, условно сохранённая в `window`, ссылается на родительский `LexicalEnvironment` через скрытое свойство `[[Scope]]`.
Сборщик просто не может удалить его - `window -> counter -> [[Scope]]`.

Это объясняет почему новый вызов `makeCounter` создал девственно чистый счётчик - каждый вызов функции выдаёт ей кристально новый `LexicalEnvironment`.

---

Замыкания - вообще очень интересная вещь, которая может быть очень мощной, а может в конец запутать, если не знать принципов работы замыканий.