# Замыкание в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, замыкания

Друзья, учу JavaScript и столкнулся с проблемой.

Вот код:

```js
function makeCounter() {
  var currentCount = 1;

  return function() { // (**)
    return currentCount++;
  };
}

var counter = makeCounter(); // (*)

// каждый вызов увеличивает счётчик и возвращает результат
alert( counter() ); // 1
alert( counter() ); // 2
alert( counter() ); // 3

// создать другой счётчик, он будет независим от первого
var counter2 = makeCounter();
alert( counter2() ); // 1
```

Счетчик работает правильно - вызвали 3 раза - значение 3 и имеет. Но почему так происходит? Ведь в функции ему каждый раз присваивается значение 1. Следовательно при каждом вызове функции он должен выдавать 1. По крайней мере так в Си подобных языках. Предположу, что так происходит потому, что переменную один раз объявили и она стала некой глобальной и в последующих заходах в эту функцию это строка просто пропускается...
В общем буду признателен за пояснение.

Comment: Раз (в общих чертах): http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/414092/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-javascript
Два, глубже: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/564433/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9

Comment: Автор, будьте внимательнее. Этот вопрос тут уже задавался, **при чем точно в такой же формулировке**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть хорошая статья про [замыкания](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures):

> Замыкания — это функции, ссылающиеся на независимые (свободные)
>   переменные. Другими словами, функция, определённая в замыкании,
>   «запоминает» окружение, в котором она была создана.

В вашем случае функция `makeCounter` возвращает функцию, которая как бы "захватила" `currentCount` и, следовательно, вызывая выполнения экземпляра `counter` - вы инкрементируете счетчик. Создавая `counter2` вы создаете новый экземпляр, который содержит в себе новый счетчик `currentCount`, поэтому они и выполняются независимо.

Вдобавок, есть уже ответ на ваш вопрос: [Как работают замыкания в JavaScript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/414092/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-javascript)