# Не получается добавить EventListener для owl carousel через цикл

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel, javascript-events

Есть 6 div с классом 'slide_icon'. Для каждого из них нужно добавить функцию скролла к определенному элементу (их 6) карусели.

Я могу написать конкретно:

```
var slide_icons = document.getElementsByClassName('slide_icon');

slide_icons[0].addEventListener('click', function(){
    $('.owl-carousel').trigger('to.owl.carousel', [0, 300]);
});
slide_icons[1].addEventListener('click', function(){
    $('.owl-carousel').trigger('to.owl.carousel', [1, 300]);
});
slide_icons[2].addEventListener('click', function(){
    $('.owl-carousel').trigger('to.owl.carousel', [2, 300]);
});
slide_icons[3].addEventListener('click', function(){
    $('.owl-carousel').trigger('to.owl.carousel', [3, 300]);
});
slide_icons[4].addEventListener('click', function(){
    $('.owl-carousel').trigger('to.owl.carousel', [4, 300]);
});
slide_icons[5].addEventListener('click', function(){
    $('.owl-carousel').trigger('to.owl.carousel', [5, 300]);
});
```

Но если попытаться сделать всё это через цикл:

```
var slide_icons = document.getElementsByClassName('slide_icon');

for (var i = 0; i < slide_icons.length; i++){
    slide_icons[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        $('.owl-carousel').trigger('to.owl.carousel', [i, 300]);
    });
}
```

Выходит так, что всем блокам 'slide_icon' добавляется функция скролла к первому элементу карусели.

Про события owl carousel можно прочитать [здесь](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-events.html).

**Собственно, вопросы: 
"Почему через цикл не работает? Как сделать так, чтобы работало?"**

Comment: Посмотрите вот этот ответ. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/614911/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-javascript?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Почему через цикл не работает?**

Пример для размышлений:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => {console.log(i)}, 100)
}
```

**Рекомендую изучить/повторить:**

[Замыкания](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B2_%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B5_%D0%9E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C_%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0.), [Перечисления](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

**Как сделать так, чтобы работало?**

Так как выполнение кода откладывается (асинхронность JS) то переменная `i` меняется аж до конца цикла.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => {console.log(i)}, 100)
}
```